# Doctrine2 conditional attribute override

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am searching for the best way to implement the following model:

attributes of entity building -> overrides attributes of  entity customer group -> overrides attributes of default

Customer group can have many buildings, so he can configure global defaults and define only for deviating terms other settings.

Example usecase: Each entity has a property theme, if theme is not defined in "building" then use theme property of "customer group", if theme property is also not defined in "customer group" than use the "default" (in default it must be defined).

In a legacy project I have done this by setting the "inherited property" to NULL if they should be taken from parent. I could imagine that this behaviour could be reached with @AttributeOverride but if I use this it is overridden anyway not only If it is not set (not entirely sure about that documentation about @AttributeOverride is marginal). My question is how could I implement this or is there a alternative way to reach this behavior?